# UWP Class Library NuGet package XamlParseException error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, nuget, class-library

Currently I'm working on an UWP NuGet package for making it easier to create great popups and dialogs.
Currently the project is newborn and doesn't have so much controls but I tried to create a NuGet package for it to be a test for making sure it is all good.
Unless I'm using app with the class library referenced to the sample project all things working well but after downloading the library from NuGet I'm getting XamlParseException error.
I searched a bit and find it out that I should add some xaml, xbf or somethings in the output so I tried to add the following lines to my nuspec.

```
    <files>
    <!-- XAML controls -->

    <file src="Controls\MessageBoxControls\MessageBoxControl.xaml" target="lib\netcore50\Controls\MessageBoxControls"/>
    <file src="bin\Debug\UWPPopupToolkit\Controls\MessageBoxControls\MessageBoxControl.xbf" target="lib\netcore50\Controls\MessageBoxControls"/>

    <file src="Controls\PopupControlControls\PopupControl.xaml" target="lib\netcore50\Controls\PopupControlControls"/>
    <file src="bin\Debug\UWPPopupToolkit\Controls\PopupControlControls\PopupControl.xbf" target="lib\netcore50\Controls\PopupControlControls"/>

    <file src="Controls\SlideupPopupControls\SlideupPopup.xaml" target="lib\netcore50\Controls\SlideupPopupControls"/>
    <file src="bin\Debug\UWPPopupToolkit\Controls\SlideupPopupControls\SlideupPopup.xbf" target="lib\netcore50\Controls\SlideupPopupControls"/>

    </files>
```

But still I'm getting same error any idea how to solve it?
I should mention that the project is currently available on Github on the following link
https://github.com/NGame1/UWPPopupToolkit
and the NuGet package also is available here
https://www.nuget.org/packages/UWPPopupToolkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Perry Qian-MSFT
Finally, I got able to fix the issue.
adding files like this

```
<files>
<!-- Dll -->
<file src="bin\Release\UWPPopupToolkit.dll" target="lib\netcore50" />

<!-- Resources -->
<file src="bin\Release\UWPPopupToolkit.pdb" target="lib\netcore50" />
<file src="bin\Release\UWPPopupToolkit.pri" target="lib\netcore50" />

<!-- IntelliSense -->
<file src="bin\Release\UWPPopupToolkit.XML" target="lib\netcore50" />

<!-- XAML control -->
<file src="bin\Release\UWPPopupToolkit\**\*.*" target="lib\netcore50\UWPPopupToolkit" />

<!-- Icon -->
<!--<file src="..\icon.png" target="images\" />-->
</files>
```

solved the problem.
You can find the result files here: [UWPPopupToolkitSDK.nuspec](https://github.com/NGame1/UWPPopupToolkit/blob/main/UWPPopupToolkit/UWPPopupToolkitSDK/UWPPopupToolkitSDK.nuspec) | [UWPPopupToolkit.props](https://github.com/NGame1/UWPPopupToolkit/blob/main/UWPPopupToolkit/UWPPopupToolkitSDK/Build/UWPPopupToolkit.props) | [UWP Popup Toolkit Github](https://github.com/NGame1/UWPPopupToolkit)

Answer (score 1):

Simply placing the content files in the `lib` folder of the nuget package will not automatically copy it into the build output folder, only the `dll`, `pdb` and `xml` files will be added into the output projects automatically.

Since your additional files are not the same type, so you cannot get what you want by your method. So I suggest you could  try this:

**Solution**

**1)** create a folder called `build` on your root directory of your project and then add a file called [<package_id>.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package) file.

**Note**: the file must be named the same as your nuget package so that it will work. **For an example**, if your nuget project named as `UWPPopupToolkit.0.0.1-rc.nupkg`, the file must be named as `UWPPopupToolkit.props`.

[image]

**2)** add these content into the `UWPPopupToolkit.props` file:

```
<Project>
    <Target Name="OutputExtraFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <ItemGroup>
            <File Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\File\**\*.*"></File>
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(File)" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"></Copy>  
    </Target>
</Project>
```

**3)** modify your `UWPPopupToolkitSDK.nuspec` file like this:

```
 <files>
        <!-- XAML controls -->

        <file src="Controls\MessageBoxControls\MessageBoxControl.xaml" target="File\Controls\MessageBoxControls"/>
        <file src="bin\Debug\UWPPopupToolkit\Controls\MessageBoxControls\MessageBoxControl.xbf" target="File\Controls\MessageBoxControls"/>

        <file src="Controls\PopupControlControls\PopupControl.xaml" target="File\Controls\PopupControlControls"/>
        <file src="bin\Debug\UWPPopupToolkit\Controls\PopupControlControls\PopupControl.xbf" target="File\Controls\PopupControlControls"/>

        <file src="Controls\SlideupPopupControls\SlideupPopup.xaml" target="File\Controls\SlideupPopupControls"/>
        <file src="bin\Debug\UWPPopupToolkit\Controls\SlideupPopupControls\SlideupPopup.xbf" target="File\Controls\SlideupPopupControls"/>
        <file src="build\UWPPopupToolkit.props" target="build" />
    </files>
```

**4)** then repack your nuget project, before you install the new version of the nuget package, please [clean the nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) and also delete the `bin`, `obj` or any output folders of your main project.

=================================

**Update 1**

**In my side**, clean all nuget caches or delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages` and then install the new version of the nuget package, the target files are output to `bin\x86\Debug\Controls`,

If I install the new version `0.0.1.5-rc`,everything works well. **See this:**

[image]

**Not sure** if your problem is that the files are missing or you want to put them into `bin\x86\Debug\netcore50\Controls`.

If your issue is the second, you should modify your `UWPPopupToolkit.props`,

use this:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(File)" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)netcore50\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"></Copy>
```

**After that, delete bin and obj folder and then rebuild your main project again.**

Comment: I did it but still, the problem is presents. I published the NuGet with your solution here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/UWPPopupToolkit/0.0.1.5-rc

Comment: Has your file not been copied into the output folder? In my side, the files are copied into `bin\x86\Debug\Controls`. Is this not enough? Or before you install this new version, you should delete all caches files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`. Then, delete `bin` and `obj` folder and then rebuild your new project again. Not  sure what your problem is: the files are missing or you want to copy them into `bin\x86\Debug\netcore50\Controls` or anything else?  See the `update 1` of my answer.

Comment: Yes, Files are copied to the bin output folder but the thing I find is that the Appx doesn't have this folder. ```bin\x64\Debug\Controls``` is available but not the ```bin\x64\Debug\AppX``` I don't know why.

Comment: If the appx is the name of your uwp project and you want them to be copied into such folder, I suggest you could change to use this: `<Copy SourceFiles="@(File)" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)$(MSBuildProjectName)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"></Copy>` in the `UWPPopupToolkit.props` file.

Comment: No Appx is the folder of the debug deployed project. When I press F5 or start debugging on the local machine then in the debug folder it creates an Appx folder witch is the registered package

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In your side, since debug process will reads the files from bin\x64\Debug\AppX\Controls\xxxx. Use this `<Copy SourceFiles="@(File)" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)AppX\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"></Copy>`